# WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, jboss, wildfly

Hello i'm trying to deploy one of the web services from my app on Wildfly 18.

This is the similar error i'm getting for most of the web services after i migrated the app from jboss eap 6.4 to wildfly 18.

There are multiple webservices out of which some them are working fine and some are throwing the following error

ERROR :

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".

INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".

INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "appWeb.war" of deployment "app.ear"
    

at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    

at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    

at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    

at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    

at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: JBWS024109: Could not get WSDL contract for endpoint com.att.aots.cmi.ChangeMgtService_ChangeMgtSoapHttpPortImpl at /wsdls/appContract.wsdl
    

at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.getWsdlLocationURL(MetadataBuilder.java:284)
    

at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder.build(MetadataBuilder.java:91)
    

at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.DescriptorDeploymentAspect.start(DescriptorDeploymentAspect.java:42)
    

at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    

at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
    ... 8 more



03:15:09,065 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 

2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
    

"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"appWeb.war\".INSTALL" => 

"WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"appWeb.war\" of deployment \"app.ear\"
    

Caused by: org.jboss.wsf.spi.WSFException: JBWS024109: Could not get WSDL contract for endpoint com.att.aots.cmi.ChangeMgtService_ChangeMgtSoapHttpPortImpl at /wsdls/appContract.wsdl"},
    

"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"appWeb.war\".deploymentCompleteService"],
    

"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"app.ear\".\"appWeb.war\".deploymentCompleteService]"]
}


03:15:09,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "app.ear" with deployment "app.ear"


03:15:09,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) 

WFLYCTL0183: Service status report


WFLYCTL0185:    Newly corrected services:
      

service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".batch.artifact.factory (new available)
      

service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".batch.environment (new available)
      

service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".beanmanager (no longer required)
      

service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".jndiDependencyService (no longer required)
      

service jboss.deployment.unit."app.ear".WeldStartService (no longer required)
      

service jboss.deployment.unit."app.ear".weld.weldClassIntrospector (no longer required)


WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."app.ear"."appWeb.war".

INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "appWeb.war" of deployment "app.ear"
```

Comment: There should be a stack trace or some more information above this in the log. There's not much to go on here.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins i've attached the entire stack trace.

Comment: I'm not a WS expert, but it looks like maybe something is wrong in your WSDL.

Comment: Yup i resolved the error, the path for the wsdl contract was given wrong